# Child controller observers still active after route change

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently working on a map application with EmberJS, using [ember-leaflet](https://github.com/gabesmed/ember-leaflet) for displaying the map. See this jsFiddle for my current setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/HUnnr/1/

My problem is, that I didn't get the click event delegated to the `PlacesNewController`, only if the `/places/new` route is open.

**my first attempt**
Delegating the `click` event from `MapView` -> `PlacesController` -> `PlacesNewController`, but that did also handle the click event and add a marker to the map, after I changed the route, because `PlacesNewController` was still alive.

**my second attempt**
Then I tried Embers `Evented` mixin. After I had delegated the event from `MapView` -> `PlacesController`, I triggered an event. I bind `PlacesNewController` to this event on `PlacesNewRoute.activate` and unbind it on `PlacesNewRoute.deactivate`. The main problem was, that I couldn't access the model of `PlacesNewController` from the event handling function.

Both solution above doesn't seem to be the "ember way". I think there is a better solution for something like this. Maybe someone could help me to solve this problem. I think, something like direct delegating map events to `PlacesNewController` would be the cleanest solution, but I didn't know how I could achieve that with Ember.

**EDIT:**
Here is a new jsBin:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uHOPOfi/23/edit

The main problem is, if you first visit `/places` route, as expected the observers for `zoom` and `isCloseEnough` are not called. After that you go to `/places/new` and the observers are working as expected. But what I didn't understand is, why after going back to `/places`, the observers and with them also the `PlacesNewController` are still active? I thought Ember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution for this problem with the hints from kingpin's answer and [this video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/emberjs-messages-views-controller-router). The main point is, that every event from the view hits the current route. So the map always delegates the click event. But then it could be processed route depended in `PlacesRoute` or `PlacesNewRoute`. So the `PlacesNewController` does all the place creation logic, the `PlacesController` does index logic and so on. I think that's a good starting point at the moment.

Here a [jsFiddle](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uHOPOfi/27#/places/new), that shows my current solution described above.

@kingpin: thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

send an action to the controller.

You can bounce actions around through controllers.

(sorry, switched to jsbin, jsfiddle doesn't fit well on my screen)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AguxORAD/3/edit

Personally I'd ditch the new route/controller, it seems weird since all of the real logic lives in places and you'll have to proxy info back and forth, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's close to my "first attempt", but there is still this problem, that the action in `PlacesNewController` is also called after I went back to `/places` route or to another route, as described in my question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to put it in a different controller?

Comment: I first thought the route handles the controller creation and then the event only is active for the new (create a marker on map) route. There I have some more logic, like adding a title, description and so on, so I want to separate the logic for that. If you have a better solution for the application layout, then it's welcome.

Comment: Controllers are long living, they don't just exist with routes.  This is why controllers can be fetched and used before a route using it is accessed.